# Specify Cookbook Version at the Node Level

Tags: chef-infra

I was wondering if it was possible for me to specify the version of a cookbook that I wanted to use at the node level. The current version is frozen and instead of unfreezing it, I'd just like to use a different version for a specific node.

I already have a run-list attached to my role for that node and I have tried to specify the run-list manually in the node default and override attributes sections respectively to no avail.

Here is an example of my attributes:

```
{
  "tags": [],
  "missionspace2": {
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[recipeOne@0.8.3]",
    "recipe[recipeTwo@0.2.0]"
  ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [specify exact cookbook version in node run\_list still possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28206866/specify-exact-cookbook-version-in-node-run-list-still-possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it at the node level in the node's run list but you cannot set a node's run list via attributes. So "yes" to the question you asked but "no" to the implementation example you used.